# How to extract array elements that are values ​of an associative array (object) one by one

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to extract one array element at a time from an associative array (object) using JavaScript.
I tried the method of extracting values ​​from an associative array, but the result was not as expected.

```js
let obj = {
  label1: [1.1, 1.4],
  label2: [1.2, 1.5],
  label3: [1.3, 1.6],
}

function test() {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    obj[key].forEach(elm => {
        console.log(elm[0]) //1
        console.log(elm[1]) //.
    }
  }
}
```

I was expecting the following results, but 1.1 was broken down.

```js
console.log(elm[0]) //1.1
console.log(elm[1]) //1.4
console.log(elm[2]) //1.7
```

Is there an effective way to extract this array element successfully?

Comment: you are accessing a string. btw, where do you get `'1.7'` from?

Comment: Please modify your questions again, makes no sense what you're asking and what you've posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need access subproperties of your "elm"

Just use

```
function test(obj) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
        //obj[key] is [1.1, 1.4]
        obj[key].forEach(elm => {
            //elm is 1.1
            console.log(elm);
        });
    });
}
```